# Using Unity DI with multiple assemblies

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, enterprise-library-5

I am in the process of developing some reusable components for a web based CMS platform, and wanted to investigate using Unity instead of Spring.NET.

In solution #1, I have developed various components in a tiered architecture.  Using Spring.NET, I can embed an XML configuration file in one of the assemblies, which declares what objects get loaded into the DI container. The point being that the builder of the component should be the one to decide which implementations are the preferred ones within the context of the component.

In my other solutions, I simply add a reference to load the configuration from the assembly, and those elements are loaded into the running container for that website.

What would the configuration strategy be for such a scenario under Unity?

Comment: With anything other than String.NET, the preferred way of doing registrations is using code based registration.

Answer (score 1):

Unity supports both [XML configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) (AKA Design-Time configuration) and [programmatic configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660858%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) (AKA Run-Time configuration). XML Configuration will have to follow [The Unity Configuration Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).

Out of the box the XML configuration hooks into .NET Configuration so if don't want to use app.config/web.config and manually load I think you will have to create your own ConfigurationSection class to load the configuration information:

```
public class MyUnityConfigurationSection : UnityConfigurationSection
{
    public string Serialize()
    {
        return SerializeSection(null, UnityConfigurationSection.SectionName, 
            ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
    }

    public void LoadConfigurationFile(string fileName)
    {
        Deserialize(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
    }

    public void Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
        using (var reader = XmlTextReader.Create(sr))
        {
            base.DeserializeSection(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can load the configuration from a string or file:

```
string configString = "<unity xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity\">\r\n  <container>\r\n    <register type=\"IEmployee\" mapTo=\"FakeEmployee\" />\r\n    </container>\r\n</unity>";

var config = new MyUnityConfigurationSection();
config.Deserialize(configString);

IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration(config);
```

You would probably want to create a method in the configuration assembly:

```
public void Configure(IUnityContainer container)
{
    // internally configure the container via XML or programmatically
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting thought...would it be possible to add a config section, and instruct unity to load all config files from a given folder for example?